# Laravel - how to use whereHas with conditional relationships?

Tags: orm, laravel-5, eager-loading

I've been trying to solve this issue for 3 days but didn't find any solution.

I have a conditional one-to-one relationship between users table and their profiles admin_profile, teacher_profile, student_profile, and company_pofile

the relationship in user model looks like this:

```
function profile() {
    switch ($this -> type) {
        case 'other':
            return $this -> hasOne('App\AdminProfile');
        break;
        case 'company':
            return $this -> hasOne('App\CompanyProfile');
        break;
        case 'teacher':
            return $this -> hasOne('App\TeacherProfile');
        break;
        case 'student':
            return $this -> hasOne('App\StudentProfile');
        break;
    }
}
```

And as it's conditional, eager loading won't work before I call "get" method or one of it's siblings. so I used "load" to get the user profile like this:

```
function getUser($id) {
    $user = User::find($id) -> load('profile');

    return response() -> json($user);
}
```

Now the problem is that I want to search users according to data in their profiles, so I did this:

```
if($request -> has('filter')) {
    $users -> whereHas('profile', function ($q) use($request) {
        $filter = explode($request -> filter, ',');
        $q -> where ($filter[0], @$filter[1]);
    });
}
```

And of course because of the conditional relationship, eager loading won't work and here is the error message:

> FatalErrorException in Builder.php line 580: Call to a member function
>   getRelationCountQuery() on null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been down this road myself, and its painful. I would highly recommend you use Laravel's Polymorphic Relationships instead. If you can't, the best way to deal with this would be to do individual queries for every relationship type. However to be able to do that, you would have to split up your relationship like so:

```
public function adminProfile {
    return $this->hasOne('App\AdminProfile');
}

public function companyProfile {
    return $this->hasOne('App\CompanyProfile');
}

public function teacherProfile {
    return $this->hasOne('App\TeacherProfile');
}

public function studentProfile {
    return $this->hasOne('App\StudentProfile');
}

public function profile() {
    switch ($this->type) {
        case 'other':
            return $this->adminProfile();
            break;
        case 'company':
            return $this->companyProfile();
            break;
        case 'teacher':
            return $this->teacherProfile();
            break;
        case 'student':
            return $this->studentProfile();
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception('Unknown Type: '. $this->type);
    }
}
```

And then get the results like so:

```
$students = User::where('type', 'student')->whereHas('studentProfile', function ($q) use($request) {
    $filter = explode($request -> filter, ',');
    $q -> where ($filter[0], @$filter[1]);
});


$teachers = User::where('type', 'teacher')->whereHas('teacherProfile', function ($q) use($request) {
    $filter = explode($request -> filter, ',');
    $q -> where ($filter[0], @$filter[1]);
});


$company = User::where('type', 'company')->whereHas('companyProfile', function ($q) use($request) {
    $filter = explode($request -> filter, ',');
    $q -> where ($filter[0], @$filter[1]);
});
```

However, if you can use Polymorphic Relationships, they have been created for this very reason, and would make things a lot easier.

"Polymorphic relations allow a model to belong to more than one other model on a single association." - Laravel knows how polymorphic relationships work, and have added support for all the eloquent functions.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think I'm stuck now because I made a lot of functionality based on 'profile'. However, I thought polymorphic relations are used for one-many and many-many relationships, right?